# Computation of row echelon form of matrix including trigonometric functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, matrix-rank

In our lectrue we consider the function $f:\{(r,\varphi,\theta)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid r>0\} \to\mathbb{R}^3$, where
\begin{align*}
&f(r,\varphi,\theta):=\begin{pmatrix}r\cos(\varphi)\cos(\theta)\\r\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)\\r\sin(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\\ &Df=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\varphi)\cos(\theta)&-r \sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)&-r\cos(\varphi)\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\varphi)\cos(\theta)&r\cos(\varphi)\cos(\theta)&-r\sin(\varphi)\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&0&r\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
We must check if rank$(Df)=3$ by computing the reduced row echelon form. Our solution says

"If $\cos(\theta)=0$ then $Df=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and If $\cos(\theta)\neq0$ then $Df=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$".

---

Only if I assume $\cos(\theta)\neq0$ **and** $\sin(\varphi)\neq 0$, $\sin(\theta)\neq 0$, $\cos(\varphi)\neq0$, then after some tedious calculation I get
$$Df=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\sin(\varphi)\cos(\varphi)\cos^2(\theta)&0\\0&0&\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}\implies Df=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Only if I assume $\cos(\theta)=0$ **and** $\sin(\varphi)\neq 0$, $\cos(\varphi)\neq0$ I get
$$
Df=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.
$$

---

I am not sure if further assumptions regarding $\sin(\varphi)$, $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\varphi)$ are missing in the solution or if there is a trick to get rid of $\sin(\theta)$, $\sin(\varphi)$, $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\varphi)$ without further assumptions?

Comment: You should not — and particularly the *solutions* should not — write that $Df$ *equals* a row-equivalent but different matrix. If $\cos\theta=0$, then $\sin\theta=\pm 1$ and your reduced echelon form is correct.

Comment: @TedShifrin, thanks for your remark! I am still a bit unsure how this helps. What about $\sin(\varphi)$ and $\cos(\varphi)$? Don't we need further assumptions on those terms too?

Comment: The lecturer/solution is correct. The spherical coordinates transformation given here is singular only when $r\cos\theta=0$. I would say that it's less tedious, actually, to calculate the determinant, which is $r^2\cos\theta$. (Pull the $r$ out of the second two columns and expand by cofactors along the third row.) If you insist on row operations, get a $1$ in the bottom right and observe that the upper left $2\times 2$ submatrix is $\left[\begin{matrix} \cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{matrix}\right]$. You can follow the $\tan\theta$ from the lower left if you wish.